# Run Terminal Command from .terminal file

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

I just figured out how to export settings from terminal which creates a `.terminal` file. And I realize that the `ExecutionString` parameter has changed to the `CommandString` parameter.

I put a command in the string tags and it worked but it jumped straight to `[Process Completed]` after it was done. Is there anyway to get it to give me a new prompt line for more commands?

Comment: Can't you start a new terminal window to enter commands?

Comment: In the .terminal file, is the "RunCommandAsShell" value set to "<true/>" ?

Comment: @Kent that was it! I don't understand exactly what that does. Could you explain?

Comment: I moved the expanded explanation in to the Answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .terminal file, `RunCommandAsShell` should not be set to `<true/>`.

This correlates to the "Run inside shell" checkbox in the "Shell" section of the preference window; which is more intuitively named.

When the preference is not selected (`RunCommandAsShell` is true), then the default shell is replaced with whatever command you've used.  If the preference is selected (`RunCommandAsShell` is either false or not listed in the .terminal file), then the command is run after the default shell is loaded for that Terminal window/tab.

Comment: thank you, this may seem like a silly question, but how can the command replace the default shell if `RunCommandAsShell` is true? Doesn't a command need a shell to run in?

Comment: It's a pretty good question.  As far as I understand it, a command doesn't need a shell but just a parent process.  There are API hooks in OSX to allow a program to execute a unix command directly, and this is probably what Terminal is doing.  Sorry if that doesn't completely answer your question, but if you want more information, I think that would be a good question to ask either here (for an apple-specific answer), or at Super User (for more general unix info).